# "Swap italics algorithm" for pure XSLT, do you know one?

Tags: algorithm, xslt, xhtml

Working with XHTML and XML tools, sometimes we need to invert the italics `<i>` blocks. Example:

```html
 <!-- original text: -->
 <p id="p1"><i>Several more</i> Homo sapiens <i>fossils were discovered</i>.</p>
 <!-- same text, swapping italics: -->
 <p id="p2">Several more <i>Homo sapiens</i> fossils were discovered.</p>
```

So, looks like this,

1. *Several more* Homo sapiens *fossils were discovered*.
2. Several more *Homo sapiens* fossils were discovered.

---

There are many ways to transform a "mixed italics" text into a "inverted italics": **see 
[What the correct algorithm to invert italics in a mixed text?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/200965/84349)**...

... But I not see any way to do it with "pure XSLT" (without external processing dependences): **do you see?**

Comment: Are you sure that moving the `i` elements around is the right solution to this? Wouldn't it better be done at the CSS level?

Comment: Yes, my problem is bigger, see [XML JATS](http://jats.niso.org/)... The "CSS level problem" [is solved](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/201792/84349) (!), see also http://jsfiddle.net/rjtzV/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello?  Someone else will edit? ... Ok, I need "100% solution", them I am adding one, only for finesh, but was not "my".

@MichaelKay and @DanielHaley show good clues and near to fineshed solutions (!).

**XML Input**

```
<html>
    <p><i>Several more</i> Homo sapiens <i>fossils were discovered</i>.</p>
    <p>Several more <i>Homo sapiens</i> fossils were discovered.</p>
    <p>Leave me alone!</p>
    <p><b><i>F</i>RAGMENT <big><i>with italics</i> and </big> withOUT</b></p>
    <p><i><sup><sub><sup><sub>Deep tags</sub></sup></sub></sup> here</i> 
       <big><b><small>and here</small></b></big>!
    </p>
</html>
```

**XSLT 1.0 implemention**

@DanielHaley show better results (only the `<p>Leave me alone!</p>` not inverted), but @MichaelKay's solution is more elegant: I merged both to produce this "100% solution". Now I am using this XSLT as "swap italics algorithm" on my system... No bugs until now (!).

```xml
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="p"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"> <!-- copy all -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="i"> <!-- remove tag i -->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[not(ancestor::i)]"> <!-- inlcude tag i -->
    <i><xsl:copy-of select="."/></i>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outlining as an "drive by event algorithm" in a copy process:

- remove `i` tags: copy any thing of  "`<i>` *thing* `</i>`" as " *thing* ".
- include `i` tags: copy any *text* as "`<i>` *text* `</i>`", when the *text* is not into a context of "italic parents (or another ancestor)". PS: *text* is a terminal node of the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would cover all cases, but you could do this:

**XML Input**

```
<html>
    <!-- original text: -->
    <p id="p1"><i>Several more</i> Homo sapiens <i>fossils were discovered</i>.</p>
    <!-- same text, swapping italics: -->
    <p id="p2">Several more <i>Homo sapiens</i> fossils were discovered.</p>
    <p>Leave me alone!</p>
    <p><b><i>O</i>RIGINAL <big><i>with italics</i> and </big> withOUT</b></p>
</html>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[i]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="swapItal"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="swapItal" priority="1">
        <i><xsl:value-of select="."/></i>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="i" mode="swapItal">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="swapItal">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="swapItal"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<html>
   <!-- original text: -->
   <p id="p1">Several more<i> Homo sapiens </i>fossils were discovered<i>.</i></p>
   <!-- same text, swapping italics: -->
   <p id="p2"><i>Several more </i>Homo sapiens<i> fossils were discovered.</i></p>
   <p>Leave me alone!</p>
   <p><b>O<i>RIGINAL </i><big>with italics<i> and </i></big><i> withOUT</i></b></p>
</html>
```

---

**Input Rendered**

*Several more* Homo sapiens *fossils were discovered*.

Several more *Homo sapiens* fossils were discovered.

Leave me alone!

***O*RIGINAL *with italics* and  withOUT**

---

**Output Rendered**

Several more *Homo sapiens* fossils were discovered*.*

*Several more* Homo sapiens *fossils were discovered.*

Leave me alone!

**O*RIGINAL* with italics *and*  *withOUT***

Comment: Updated with more complex example from http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/201803/50579

Comment: Good, thanks a lot!  It runs and I try with `<p><i><sup><sub><sup><sub>Deep tags</sub></sup></sub></sup> here</i> <big><b><small>and here</small></b></big>!</p>`, and the unique problem was lost a space producing "hereand" (perhaps a `xsl:strip-space` problem). Question: why "Leave me alone!" not inverted? I not see where the paragraph is defined as "unit for check italics".

Comment: @PeterKrauss - "Leave me alone!" wasn't inverted because there were no italics. I wanted a `<p>` that didn't have any to make sure it didn't get modified. I will take a look at your example and see if I can see why that space is getting dropped.

Comment: @PeterKrauss - Yes you're right. It's the `xsl:strip-space`. You can add this: `<xsl:preserve-space elements="p"/>` and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="i" mode="invert-italic">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="invert-italic"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[not(ancestor::i)]" mode="invert-italic">
  <i><xsl:copy-of select="."/></i>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="invert-italic">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="invert-italic"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot by the clues, showing that the `not(ancestor::i)` selector and the identity transform are foundations. I suppose that is XSLT1... Unfortunately it not runs without adaptations, generates only text values, without tags. I am testing my adaptations...